# Do I really need to use {% load static %} in Django Templates?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles, static-files

I am using Django 3, the latest version. I have defined the static files directories properly as required.
Currently to display an image, both the following source codes work fine.

Code 1:

```
<img src="static/img/logo.png">
```

Code 2:

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static 'img/logo.png' %}">
```

Since both the code snippets are working and running fine without any problems, I am wondering why not to simply use the way of Code 1 above and refrain from the extra lines of Code 2.

Which one would be beneficial and why? Please guide.

Comment: You should - to have it configurable. And behavior of your solution should be predictable for other participants (and yourself some time later). By the way your sample code 1 has a flaw: it is missing leading slash which makes this url relative to current page url, so it won't work in any pages except root-level pages.

Comment: Code 1 is working and there is no root level folder named static. It is taking the global static defined in settings.py
I understand the making it configurable part, but I would not change the name of "static" for the duration of the project.

Comment: `code 1` does not use anything from settings.py, and given url is still relative. And I'm afraid I did not talk about any folders at all, only about urls.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. From what I understood is that since this is my base project level master templates, it won't have any effect. However I cannot use the similar pattern in further apps with different levels of templates which are nests within multiple level urls. Would you still advice that the Case 1 can be used in master/base project level templates just to save the performance overhead?

Comment: Not templates but URLs. A template does not know and care, in response to which URL request it'll be rendered. `<img src="static/img/logo.png">` - wrong, because relative, `<img src="/static/img/logo.png">` - correct. However, it is still recommended to use `{% static 'asdf' %}` template tag everywhere you refer to static files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base/master level templates would work without static tag and maybe considered for performance.

However for other level templates either nested or in app templates or nested urls, it's required to be reference with static as it would minimise chances of error. So for all other templates it is recommended to use static tag.